# Failing in Code coverage Test with a simple class constructor

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, code-coverage, nmock

I have a class:

```
 public class SourceServerProvider : ISourceServerProvider
    {
        private readonly ISourceServer _sourceServer;
        public SourceServerProvider()
            :this(new SourceServer())
        { }

        public SourceServerProvider(ISourceServer sourceServer)
        {
            _sourceServer = sourceServer;
        }
     }
```

MS code coverage test complaints to this block:

```
public SourceServerProvider()
            :this(new SourceServer())
        { }
```

I don't know how to write a unit test for above block. Please advise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested it with the followig code:

```
public class SourceServerProvider : ISourceServerProvider
{
private readonly ISourceServer _sourceServer;
public SourceServerProvider()
    : this(new SourceServer())
{ }

public SourceServerProvider(ISourceServer sourceServer)
{
    _sourceServer = sourceServer;
}
}

public interface ISourceServer
{
}

public class SourceServer : ISourceServer
{
}

public interface ISourceServerProvider
{
}
```

and wrote this test

```
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void test()
    {
        var a = new SourceServerProvider();
    }
}
```

Code Coverage says it is fully covered:
[image: here]

so please add the result you are getting or create asimple test that call the default ctor